# using the read.csv.sql function and loading in a subset of the data

Tags: r

I have a very large data set that I am trying to read using the `read.csv.sql` function but I cannot seem to load in any data. I run the following where I want to subset the data I am Reading in so that it reads all "Market_Names" which are Chicago. However I have some White space in the column. Basically what is happening is that R attepts to read in the csv file and filter by the market name but it loads 0 observations.

Where am I going wrong? - I include the White space in the `read.csv.sql` function. Could I use `str_detect` also here?

```
library(sqldf)
data2 <- read.csv.sql("c:/Data/data/mydata.csv", 
                      sql = "select * from file where Market_Name = ' CHICAGO             ' ")
```

DATA:

```
structure(list(MskdName = c(" Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", 
" Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", 
" Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", 
" Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", 
" Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", 
" Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", 
" Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", 
" Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", 
" Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", 
" Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", 
" Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", 
" Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", 
" Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", 
" Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", 
" Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", 
" Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", 
" Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", 
" Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", 
" Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", 
" Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", " Chain55 ", 
" Chain55 ", " Chain55 "), Market_Name = c(" CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", 
" CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             ", " CHICAGO             "
), WEEK = c(1114L, 1115L, 1116L, 1119L, 1121L, 1122L, 1123L, 
1124L, 1125L, 1128L, 1130L, 1132L, 1135L, 1141L, 1143L, 1159L, 
1160L, 1134L, 1135L, 1136L, 1115L, 1118L, 1120L, 1123L, 1125L, 
1127L, 1128L, 1132L, 1140L, 1141L, 1150L, 1155L, 1114L, 1114L, 
1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 
1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 
1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 
1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 
1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 
1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 
1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 
1114L, 1114L, 1114L), SY = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L), GE = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L), DOLLARS = c(5.38, 2.69, 10.76, 10.76, 5.38, 5.38, 2.69, 
2.69, 2.69, 2.69, 2.69, 3.39, 6.78, 3.39, 3.39, 3.39, 3.39, 3.39, 
3.39, 3.39, 2.69, 2.69, 2.69, 2.69, 2.69, 5.38, 5.38, 2.69, 3.39, 
3.39, 6.78, 6.78, 16.58, 22.26, 9.98, 33.96, 247.45, 203.31, 
44.91, 11.99, 19.96, 19.47, 23.97, 462.43, 157.92, 49.9, 6.58, 
21.82, 42.77, 181.82, 13.98, 13.16, 69.93, 12.49, 6.99, 22.9, 
35.97, 10.91, 7.99, 4.99, 3.99, 29.97, 5.49, 12.87, 15.98, 8.58, 
2.49, 36.36, 13.98, 11.48, 11.98, 21.8, 122.69, 120.01, 13.62, 
22.22, 20, 54.96, 2.69, 23.96, 32.97, 17.97, 32.97, 23.96, 11.98, 
15.98, 19.96, 20.12, 20.97, 15.57, 11.82, 16.76, 4.99, 28.28, 
98.2, 43.63, 14.97, 12.98, 19.98, 17.97)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000008ec1ef0>)
```

EDIT:

I get this warning the first time I run the code (afterwards no warning):

```
Warning message:
In .Internal(putconst(constBuf, constCount, x)) :
  closing unused connection 3 (C:\Users\user\Documents\sqltest.csv)
```

After running the following:

```
dataxyz <- read.csv.sql("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\sqltest.csv", 
                         "select * from file where Market_Name = 'NEWYORK'", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

SESSION INFO:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] sqldf_0.4-11  RSQLite_2.1.1 gsubfn_0.7    proto_1.0.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.0                 MASS_7.3-51.1              quantstrat_0.14.6         
 [4] FinancialInstrument_1.3.1  bit_1.1-14                 lattice_0.20-38           
 [7] quadprog_1.5-5             foreach_1.4.4              TTR_0.23-4                
[10] blob_1.1.1                 tcltk_3.5.2                tools_3.5.2               
[13] xts_0.11-2                 PerformanceAnalytics_1.5.2 quantmod_0.4-13.1         
[16] grid_3.5.2                 DBI_1.0.0                  iterators_1.0.10          
[19] digest_0.6.18              yaml_2.2.0                 bit64_0.9-7               
[22] blotter_0.14.2             codetools_0.2-15           curl_3.3                  
[25] memoise_1.1.0              compiler_3.5.2             boot_1.3-20               
[28] chron_2.3-53               pkgconfig_2.0.2            zoo_1.8-4                 
Warning messages:
1: In if (!missing(a) && mayCallBrowser(a, cntxt)) return(TRUE) :
  closing unused connection 5 (C:\Users\Matt\Documents\sqltest.csv)
2: In if (!missing(a) && mayCallBrowser(a, cntxt)) return(TRUE) :
  closing unused connection 3 (C:\Users\Matt\Documents\sqltest.csv)
```

Here is the file I am trying to read in:

https://ufile.io/e6f8z

EDIT 2:
The suggestions work great, thanks! just a small minor problem. The data reads in as something like the following:

```
         X IRI_KEY WEEK SY GE  VEND ITEM UNITS DOLLARS      F D PR                 UPC    OU     EST_ACV Market_Name
1 "105983"  264929 1114  0  2 18200  495     5    6.45 "NONE" 0  0 "00-02-18200-00495" " GR" " 26.67499"    "TOLEDO"
    Open    Clsd    MskdName                                  L1                                 L2
1 " 913" " 1419" " Chain57 " "CATEGORY - BEER/ALE/ALCOHOLIC CID" "DOMESTIC BEER/ALE (INC NON-ALCOH"
                    L3                   L4        L5                           L9 VOL_EQ
1 "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC" "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC" "BUD ICE" "+BUDIC LAGER BEER CAN 24OZ" 0.0833
                                                                  STUBSPEC
1 "+BUDIC LAGER BEER CAN       24OZ 0 2 18200   495 1  1 0.0833RP   00335"
```

Which breaking down a few columns looks like:

```
                  UPC     EST_ACV Market_Name
1 "00-02-18200-00495" " 26.67499"    "TOLEDO"
```

with structure like the following:

```
> peak %>%
+   select(UPC, EST_ACV, Market_Name) %>%
+ head(1) %>%
+   str()
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ UPC        : chr "\"00-02-18200-00495\""
 $ EST_ACV    : chr "\" 26.67499\""
 $ Market_Name: chr "\"TOLEDO\""
```

So I have `"` added to the data. Not a major problem since I can use gsub to eliminate them, I just wanted to know if its possible to import the data without.

Comment: Using the following: `data2 <- read.csv.sql("E:/IRI Data/all_beer_data/year1.csv", 
                      sql = SELECT * FROM file WHERE replace(Market_Name, " ","") = 'CHICAGO')` I get an error: `Error: unexpected symbol in:
"data2 <- read.csv.sql("E:/IRI Data/all_beer_data/year1.csv", 
                      sql = SELECT * FROM file"`

Comment: Just tested and this works: `read.csv.sql("testsql.csv", "SELECT * FROM file WHERE Market_Name LIKE '%CHICAGO%'")`

Comment: Thanks! This does seem to work also on the whole data set but I am getting some very strange results (regarding other columns in the data). I will need to go back through and re-créate the original data to see if I have no mistake there. I will update as soon as I can

Comment: Can also use `... where trim(Market_Name) = 'CHICAGO'` .  Try both this and the solution in @Mako212's comment to see which is faster if performance is important.

Comment: @Mako212 and G. Grothendieck can you let me know what version you are using of sqldf? Everything I am trying in importing 0 observations - just importing the columns with no obs

Comment: @user8959427 I'm using `sqldf_0.4-11` and `R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)`

Comment: Thanks, it seems I have the same version as you. I have made a small edit to the original post (at the bottom). Could you please let me know if you can read in the csv file from your side?

Comment: @user8959427 Using your linked file, `read.csv.sql(file, "SELECT * FROM file WHERE Market_Name LIKE '%CHICAGO%'")` correctly returns the one row where `Market_Name` contains "CHICAGO" for me.

Comment: Note that @G.Grothendieck's `trim` solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: It Works for me also now! thanks :) One small point, I get warning messages `Warning messages:
1: closing unused connection 4 (C:\Users\user\Documents\sqltest.csv) 
2: closing unused connection 3 (C:\Users\user\Documents\sqltest.csv) ` Is there some line of code I should include to "close" the connection myself?

Comment: `closeAllConnections()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I real appreciate it. It seems to work now, however I made a small edit to the original post. Do you have any suggestion on how to solve this issue? - not the most important issue however.